# Access FormView in the ItemUpdated event

Tags: asp.net, formview

When I want to modify a FormView element like below, it works fine in the DataBound event, but it doesn't work with the ItemUpdated event (and also not with the ItemUpdating event). Why is that?

**This works**

```
Protected Sub FormView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBound        
    cType(sender.FindControl("myField"),TextBox).text="Some value"  
End Sub
```

**This does not work**

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ItemUpdated(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemUpdated
    cType(sender.FindControl("myField"),TextBox).text="Some value"  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a FormView.DataBound event after the FormView.ItemUpdated event, which causes this.